How to verify in the backend ASP.NET Core API that the token provided by front-end react app that uses GitHub OAuth is valid?
I'm building a Next.js web app with ASP.NET Core API for backend.
The problem is that I don't know how to check, that the user sending the request is authenticated (and later authorized) to send the request.
I've seen some ideas of just trying to use the token with GitHub API (that i will use to retrieve some users data about repository and commits), but not all of the requests directed to my backend API will interact with GitHub API (for example they might just retrieve data from SQL database).
How can I validate users session?
I want to send the token that GitHub OAuth provider have sent me, and check on the backend if the session of request-maker is valid and if I can allow the request to be made (with knowing what are the user data like username).

Hi @Dark_Noone, You can validate the GitHub token using GitHub’s /user API endpoint. Then implement a custom authentication handler to validate tokens globally in your ASP.NET Core API.
